# Is it possible to apply a function using `.map()` to every element of a nested vector in Rust?

Tags: rust, closures

Is it possible to apply a closure or function to every element of a `Vec<Vec<T>>` ?

Can this be done with `.map()`? If not, then is there an alternative?

I want to convert a `Vec<Vec<Option<f64>>>` to a `Vec<Vec<f64>>`. My first thoughts on how to do this are to use `.map()` plus a closure.

When I attempted this, I found that `.iter().map(f)` was not the right way, as this applied `f` to every element of the first `Vec`, and those elements are themselves `Vec`s.

I also investigated `iter().flatten()` but this produces a `Vec<T>` containing all the elements from `Vec<Vec<T>>` which "destroys" the 2-dimensional structure, which I need to keep.

I guess one possible way would be to make the closure logic of `f` to be something which itself calls `iter().map(g)`, where `g` does the desired conversion from `Option<f64> -> f64`. But this is perhaps a bit inelegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```rust
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![vec![Some(1.), None, Some(2.)]];

    let vec2 = vec.iter().map(|inner_vec| {
        inner_vec.iter().map(|option| {
            option.unwrap_or(0.)
        }).collect::<Vec<_>>()
    }).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    println!("vec2: {:?}", vec2);
}

// Program output:
// vec2: [[1.0, 0.0, 2.0]]
```

Basically, you can iterate over the outermost Vec and map its elements. These elements are inner vecs that you can (again) iterate over and map its elements. You can then apply some operation to the inner `Option<f64>` such as `.unwrap_or(0.)` and then re-collect both levels of nesting back into Vecs again.

Answer (score 1):

You are close with `flatten` but instead of applying it at the outer `Vec`, we can map over the outer `Vec` and apply `flatten` on the inner `Vec<Option<f64>>`.

```
let nested_option_numbers: Vec<Vec<Option<f64>>> = vec![
    vec![Some(3.0), None, Some(5.0)],
    vec![Some(1.0), Some(2.0), None],
    vec![None, Some(4.0)],
];

let nested_numbers: Vec<Vec<f64>> = nested_option_numbers
    .iter()
    .map(|option_numbers| option_numbers.iter().flatten().cloned().collect())
    .collect();

println!("{nested_numbers:?}");
```

This prints `[[3.0, 5.0], [1.0, 2.0], [4.0]]`.